# Looking for a Data Protection solution for Microsoft SharePoint - File protection and AGSCS compliant

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, security, security-token-service

I have been asked if there is any third party tool or some way store document and files in a very secure environment.
Basically another layer of security.
Can SharePoint Online ne used for this orwe will have to go fo a SharePoint onpremise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you, you can save files in SharePoint. The management of all content in SharePoint requires authentication of identity and permissions. To learn how SharePoint protects your data, read this article: [How SharePoint and OneDrive safeguard your data in the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/safeguarding-your-data).